# Using rrule to assign days to relevant months

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-dateutil, rrule

I was able to list the days between two dates using rrule like so:

```
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import datetime

a = '20180306'
b = '20180506'

for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY,
                  dtstart = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d'),
                  until = datetime.strptime(b, '%Y%m%d')):
    print (dt.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

the output given is:

```
20180306
20180307
...
20180408
20180409
...
20180506
```

How can I go about assigning these days to their relevant months to give an output of:

```
March-18: 26 days
April-18: 30 days
May-18: 6 days
```

I am also curious about how to extend this to include hours in the calculation ie.

```
March-18: 11.9 days
```

Thanks
**black.mamba**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and extract the length of each group. In the below example, both `grouper` and `res` are lazy iterators, so you can extract results by iteration.

```
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

a = '20180306'
b = '20180506'

rule = rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY,
                   dtstart=datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d'),
                   until=datetime.strptime(b, '%Y%m%d'))

grouper = groupby(rule, key=lambda x: x.strftime('%B-%y'))

res = ((i, len(list(j))) for i, j in grouper)

for month, count in res:
    print('{0}: {1} days'.format(month, count))

March-18: 26 days
April-18: 30 days
May-18: 6 days
```

Comment: If the dates were to change to include hours and minutes. eg. a = '09/05/2018 16:54:00' and b = '22/06/2018  12:15:00'

would this method be able to accurately output the difference as a float to 3 d.p? eg. Output: May-18: 22.30 days and Jun-18: 21.51 days ?

Comment: @black.mamba, You'd have to do a bit more work: instead of `len(list(j))`, you would have `foo(list(j))`, where `foo` is a function which takes the first and last date and outputs the difference including time.